# Creating Word documents from excel table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to create word documents based on an excel table as follows:

[image]

At the end this creates 3 documents and each one has only the lines with Yes corresponding to it. My problem is that it doesn't keep the formatting of the lines. Can somebody help me with this? Here is the code:

```
Sub NewWordDocument()

Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim LineCount As Integer
Dim DocumentCount As Integer

LineCount = Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) ' To see how many lines should be inputed
DocumentCount = Application.CountA(Range("B2:AZ2")) 'To see how many documents should be created

For j = 1 To DocumentCount
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add ' or 'Set wrdDoc =wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Foldername\Filename.doc") 'sample word operations

    wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:="Heading One"

    With wrdDoc    
    For i = 1 To LineCount
        If Cells(i + 2, j + 1).Value = "Yes" Then
            .Range.InsertAfter Cells(i + 2, 1) 'Different way to paste the text. It doesn't keep the formatting
            .Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        End If
    Next i

    If Dir("D:\" & Cells(2, j + 1).Value & ".docx") <> "" Then
    Kill "D:\" & Cells(2, j + 1).Value & ".docx"
    End If

    .SaveAs ("D:\" & Cells(2, j + 1).Value & ".docx")
    .Close ' close the document
    End With
    wrdApp.Quit ' close the Word application
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing

Next j
End Sub
```

If I do it manually, copying the cell and pasting it in word works perfectly - keeps the format and removes the table but when I use 'Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False' instead of 'InsertAfter' , I simply overwrite the same text instead of adding to the end of the page.

Also, how can I format the "Heading one" to be bold and center?

Comment: I'm a bit shaky about what the resulting Word document should contain. You say this should give three files - not five? File 1 should contain Line 1, Line 3, and Line 4 with the font formatting, but not the table structure? And each of these should be a paragraph, one beneath the other in the document?

Comment: Yes, I didn't explain it very clearly.
1. In the picture case it should give 5 files.
2. I didn't want it to create table cells that contain "Line 1" in the word file - it should paste only the text and format
3. You are right, Each of these I want to be on a new paragraph.
I made a solution - its probably very messy but I will post it in case it is useful for someone in the future.

Comment: Are you interested in how you can optimize what you posted, or happy with what you have that works? If the latter, please do click the check mark at the left of your Answer to mark it as "the" answer :-)

Comment: I will mark it as answered as soon as the 2 day time constraint is over. In the meantime, if somebody has some tips on optimization, I will be happy to read them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - it is probably not the best way to do it but it more or less  works for me.

```
Sub NewWordDocument()

Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim LineCount As Integer
Dim DocumentCount As Integer

LineCount = Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) ' To see how many lines should be inputed
DocumentCount = Application.CountA(Range("B2:AZ2")) 'To see how many documents should be created

For j = 1 To DocumentCount
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add ' or 'Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Foldername\Filename.doc") 'sample word operations

wrdApp.Selection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
wrdApp.Selection.Font.Size = 18
wrdApp.Selection.Font.Allcaps = True
wrdApp.Selection.Font.Bold = True
wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:="Title"

With wrdDoc
.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add _
    PageNumberAlignment:=wdAlignPageNumberRight, _
    FirstPage:=True

.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Header text" 'Add text in the header
.Content.InsertParagraphAfter

For i = 1 To LineCount
    If Cells(i + 2, j + 1).Value = "Yes" Then
         Range("A" & i + 2).Copy
         wrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\Page"
         wrdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
         wrdApp.Selection.PasteSpecial
        .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
    End If
Next i

        wrdApp.Selection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        wrdApp.Selection.Font.Size = 11
        wrdApp.Selection.Font.Allcaps = False
        wrdApp.Selection.Font.Bold = False
wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:="Ending Text"


If Dir("D:\" & Cells(2, j + 1).Value & ".docx") <> "" Then
Kill "D:\" & Cells(2, j + 1).Value & ".docx"
End If

.SaveAs ("D:\" & Cells(2, j + 1).Value & ".docx")
.Close ' close the document
End With
wrdApp.Quit ' close the Word application
Set wrdDoc = Nothing
Set wrdApp = Nothing


Next j

End Sub
```